# I need all users details from ADFS using c# in single outgoing claim

Tags: c#-4.0, ldap, adfs, claims, claims-authentication

hi I created the custom claim for that so please check the below claim which is created by me:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"] =] issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname"), query = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person));mail,givenName;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

But in this case, I got all emails in an outgoing claim (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress ), Also get all the givenname in another outgoing claim (http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname).

Please check the below Screenshot of how I got the values of email and name right now from the adfs using code of C#.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/storage/attachments/137282-image.png

But I need in a single outgoing claim like email= abc@gmail.com, Givenname=abc (with any comma separate or any separator), I need both email and given name in one single outgoing claim.

I already generate this same in the Microsoft Ignite forum: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/566015/how-to-get-all-users-of-adfs-with-all-attributes-e.html

Can you please help me to get all user's details from adfs using windows account login and get all user's details?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't out of the box.

That's not how claims work.

You could use a [custom attribute store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cloudpfe/how-to-create-a-custom-attribute-store-for-active-directory-federation-services-3-0).

You could also combine the claims into a single type.

See [this](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/adfs-claims-rules-c8e877faf352) under "Combining Claim Values".

Comment: I check this link ( custom attribute store.) but there is create an attribute with its value so basically, I don't add any value on that but I need to get value from the ADFS.

so its set data in attribute and then get from that attribute but I dont need to set I just get all users from adfs after windowsaccount authentication.

Please check this link : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/custom-attributes-in-c-sharp/

Comment: Your question was about combing two claims into a single one. You pass both into the custom store, join them and pass the combined result back.